# codeaurora how to git merge release tag onto kernel/msm-4.4?

Tags: android, git, kernel

Heyyo, so I've been trying to learn how to develop Android kernels and learning git which is also new to me.

So I was able to successfully clone the Code Aurora Forum kernel/msm-4.4 using this:

```
git clone https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/kernel/msm-4.4 -b LA.HB.1.1.5.c1
```

but the issue I'm having is I haven't yet been able to figure out how to merge tags. For example I've seen people update their CAF based msm8996 msm-3.18 kernels like so with the Nougat releases like so:

> Merge tag 'LA.UM.5.5.r1-05800-8x96.0' into cm-14.1
>   https://github.com/LineageOS/android_kernel_leeco_msm8996/commit/edfa6eebad37453b065eb003f19a8ad5f835b378

Here's my config in .git for my msm-4.4 kernel if there's something I need to change there

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/kernel/msm-4.4
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "LA.HB.1.1.5.c1"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/LA.HB.1.1.5.c1
```

For now, I've been attempting to port the kernel to msm-4.4 to try and teach myself a little more about Android kernels and I haven't been able to find a good guide on merging release tags so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to merge LA.UM.5.5.r1-06300-8x96.0 tag for msm8996

Comment: `Merge tag` is nothing more than [git merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge). So, what is a **specific** problem with mergeing you faced with?

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. From what I've seen on github for other kernels is they clone a kernel such as msm-3.18 and then they merge a release tag from here for specific updates for their architecture
https://wiki.codeaurora.org/xwiki/bin/QAEP/release

I have been able to git clone "msm-4.4" kernel branch "LA.HB.1.1.5.c1" but when I tried to merge tag " LA.UM.5.5.r1-06300-8x96.0" since I'm working with msm8996 on  07.01.02 I have failed in my attempts.

Or maybe my understanding of Code Aurora Forum is incorrect? Sorry if my question is confusing

Answer (score 1):

Ah shoot. Now I understand what I'm doing wrong. I was trying to merge tags from CAF releases that were not for msm-4.4. Makes sense now why it wasn't working for me.

I managed to find this guide which helped me figure that out
https://gist.github.com/DD3Boh/6c51fd3c5f91b1042e956771483714de

> First go here:
>
> https://wiki.codeaurora.org/xwiki/bin/QAEP/release
>
> This site gives information about all msm soc release details with tag
>   + android version
>
> Search your msm here.. Check the latest one and look for correct
>   android version and mark that tag.
>
> Now open one of the following links (dependent on your linux kernel
>   version)
>
> 3.10: https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/kernel/msm-3.10/
>   3.18: https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/kernel/msm-3.18/
>   4.4: https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/kernel/msm-4.4/
>
> Choose the right one and copy it, now go into your kernel folder with
>   a terminal and do
>
> ```
> git fetch <repo link> <tag>
> ```
>
> example:
>
> ```
> git fetch https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/kernel/msm-3.18/ LA.UM.5.5.r1-05300-8x96.0
> ```
>
> Then to do the merge you just have to do
>
> ```
> git merge FETCH_HEAD
> ```
>
> Now just fix the conflicts if there and then do
>
> ```
> git add -A
> git merge --continue
>  Congratulation, you have (probably) succesfully merged a new caf tag.
> ```

the only thing this guide doesn't mention is `git mergetool` which seems to be handy for fixing conflicts.